# If-else statements to cut down processing time

Tags: process, shortcut

Suppose I have a number of possible inputs from the user of my program listed from most likely to least as input1, input2, input3,...,inputN. Would the following framework cut down on processing time by accessing the most probable If statement needed first and then ignoring the rest (rather than testing the validity of each If statement thereafter)? I assume the least probable inputN will be extra burdensome on the processor, but the limited likelihood of the user giving that input makes it worth it if this structure reduces processing time overall.

```
If (input1) then (output1)
Else
    If (input2) then (output2)
    Else
        If (input3) then:(output3)
        Else
            If ...

            ... Else
                    OutputN
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how if-else-if statements work.

```
if(booleanTest1)
{
   //do a thing
}
else if(booleanTest2)
{
   //do another thing
}
//...ad infinitum
else
{
   //do default behavior
}
```

If booleanTest1 is true, we execute its code, and then skip past all the other tests.

If you're comparing one variable against many possible values, use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure, but I'd assume, that a switch-case wolud be more efficient during runtime, because of branch prediction. With If-elses you have many branches, that might go wrong, which is not good for the piped commands in the processor que.
If there are really a lot of possibilities.

I usually do ist with a map / dictionary of <Key, Method to call>. As long as they have the same signature, this might work. It may not be as fast as a switch-case, but it will grant you  some flexilibity, when you need to react to new inputs.

example:
    Dictionary myDic = new Dictionary();
    myDic.Add(input1,() => What ever to do when input1 comes);

the call the looks like this:
    myDicinput1;